# React Native Image behaves differently in dev mode than it does in production mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I built an iOS app with React Native. I used Expo to build it. In dev mode, I have an image that I manipulate and it works as expected. In production mode the image is zoomed in and cut off. Here is the code:

```
<Image
    source={require("../assets/Logo.png")}
    resizeMode={"center"}
    style={{
        resizeMode: "center",
        transform: [{ scale: 0.8 }],
        width: 250,
        height: 75,
    }}
/>
```

The reason I have both the resizeMode prop and the style is because it wasn't working earlier so I just added both in hopes that one of them would work. Please let me know if you know what the problem might be. Thanks.

[image: Dev Mode]

[image: Production Mode]

Comment: Could you share screenshots of how the image looks like in your dev vs. prod mode?

Comment: I just updated my post

Comment: This certainly looks bizarre. From personal experience, the first line of defense against bizarre things in react native is to clean your project and re-build everything. If you haven't done so yet, it's highly recommended. [react-native-clean-project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clean-project) is the tool for this job. See if the problem goes away after your project is cleaned.

Comment: I'm using Expo's managed workflow so I'm not sure that it will work.

Comment: Hmm, you are probably right. Maybe try [this](https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/clear-cache-macos-linux/) to clear old cache and start fresh.

Comment: I did that and it still isn't working. This is my first time creating a new build in about a month. Since then some things may have changed with Expo. I also updated my eas-cli which could be contributing to this.

Answer (score 1):

There is the issue with `center` resize mode in iOS, see the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28670) for details.

Use `contain` instead, which is probably the right approach anyway in this case.

> contain: Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

See all [options](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode) for resize mode.